# How to fix a warning when compiling a project

Tags: c, linux

[image: screen error]

Task: It is necessary to develop a multiprocess application. The original process is manager, accepts keyboard input and controls child processes. By pressing the ‘+’ key, a new process is added, “-” - the last added one is deleted, ‘q’ - the program ends. Each child process character-by-character displays in the eternal loop its own unique string. At the same time, the string output operation must be atomic, i.e. the output process must be synchronized so that the lines on the screen are not mixed up. Signals / events should be used as a synchronization method.
How can I correct these errors?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ncurses.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #define MAX_COUNT 10
    /*
    char strings[10][30] = {{"\r\n1) First process"}, {"\r\n2) Second process"}, {"\r\n3) Third process"}, {"\r\n4) Fourth process"}, {"\r\n5) Fifth process"} , {"\r\n6) Sixth process"}, {"\r\n7) Seventh process"},{"\r\n8) Eighth process"}, {"\r\n9) Ninth process"}, {"\r\n10) Tenth process"}};
    */

    char strings[10][30] = {{"1) First process"}, {"2) Second process"}, {"3) Third process"}, {"4) Fourth process"}, {"5) Fifth process"} , {"6) Sixth process"}, {"7) Seventh process"},{"8) Eighth process"}, {"9) Ninth process"}, {"10) Tenth process"}};

    int printFlag = 0;
    int flagEnd = 1;

    struct sigaction printSignal, endSignal;

    void canPrint(int signo)
    {
      printFlag = 1;
    }

    void setEndFlag(int signo)
    {
      flagEnd = 1;
    }

    int main(void)
    {
      int currentNum = 0;
      int processNumber = 0;

      int flag = 0;

      initscr();
      clear();
      noecho();
      refresh();

      printSignal.sa_handler = canPrint;
      sigaction(SIGUSR1,&printSignal,NULL);

      endSignal.sa_handler = setEndFlag;
      sigaction(SIGUSR2,&endSignal,NULL);

      char c = 0;
      int i = 0;

      pid_t cpid[MAX_COUNT];


      while(c!='q')
      {
        c = getchar();

        switch(c)
        {
          case '+':   
        if(processNumber < MAX_COUNT)
        {
          cpid[processNumber] = fork();   
          processNumber++;

          switch(cpid[processNumber-1])
          {
            case 0:
              flagEnd = 0;
              while(!flagEnd)
              {
            usleep(10000); 
            if(printFlag)
            {
              for(i=0; i<strlen(strings[processNumber-1]); i++)
              {
                if(flagEnd)         
                  return 0;

                printf("%c",strings[processNumber-1][i]);
                refresh();
                usleep(70000);
              }
              refresh();
              printFlag = 0;
              kill(getppid(),SIGUSR2);
            }
              }
              return 0;
              break;

            case -1:
              printf("Error!\n");
              break;

            default:  
              break;        
          }
        }
        break;

          case '-':
        if(processNumber > 0)
        {
          kill(cpid[processNumber-1],SIGUSR2);  
          waitpid(cpid[processNumber-1],NULL,NULL);//??? 

          processNumber--;  

          if (currentNum >= processNumber)  
          {
            currentNum = 0; 
            flag = 1;                       
            flagEnd = 1;    
          }

        }       
            break;
        }

        if(flagEnd && processNumber>0)       
        {
          flagEnd = 0;
          if(currentNum >= processNumber - 1)   
        currentNum = 0;              
          else if(!flag) currentNum++;     

          flag = 0;

          kill(cpid[currentNum],SIGUSR1); 
        } 
        refresh();        
      }


      if(cpid[processNumber-1]!=0)
        for(;processNumber>=0;processNumber--)
        {
          kill(cpid[processNumber-1],SIGUSR2);
          waitpid(cpid[processNumber-1],NULL,NULL);//???
        }

      clear();  
      endwin();

      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What is the warning message, and on which line?

Comment: replace NULL by 0

Comment: The [man page for `waitpid`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/wait)clearly says the third argument is `int`. So, pass an `int`, not a `void*`.

Comment: What is unclear about the compiler warning: expected `int` but given `void *`?

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> w.c:97:46: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘waitpid’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>            waitpid(cpid[processNumber-1],NULL,NULL);//???
>
> In file included from w.c:8:0:
> /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/wait.h:86:16: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
>  extern __pid_t waitpid (__pid_t __pid, int *__stat_loc, int __options);
> ```

the third argument must be an *int*, *NULL* is not an *int* but a pointer (`((void*) 0)` as you can see in your warning), replace it by 0, so `waitpid(cpid[processNumber-1], NULL, 0);`